# Error while looking for vmd executable

Tags: import, path

I'm trying to import a VMD file with the BlendMol add-on (https://durrantlab.pitt.edu/blendmol/). I have followed the steps in the video guide (https://git.durrantlab.pitt.edu/jdurrant/blendmol/) but when I try to import a vmd or pdb file I get following error:

[image]

I'm working on Windows 10, Blender 3.1.0 and VMD version 1.9.4a53 (https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/)

Has anyone had the same problem? Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: you should probably contact the creator of the addon as this is an exception on their end and not blender software. i see someone else had similar problem https://durrantlab.pitt.edu/forums/topic/windows-import/ but no response from them.

Comment: Thanks! I will follow your advice.